# How could this assignment work?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am using WF 4.5. I have the following working code snippet:

```
        Variable<Int32> varAdd1 = new Variable<Int32>();
        varAdd1.Name = "varAdd1";
        varAdd1.Default = 5;

        Assign<Int32> assignActivity1 = new Assign<int>();
        assignActivity1.To = varAdd1; // <====== HERE
```

The `assignActivity1.To` is of type `OutArgument<T>`. The `varAdd1` is of type `Variable<Int32>`.
I checked these 2 types' hierarchy. They don't share any common base type.

The hierarchy of these 2 types are:

> OutArgument`<T>` -> OutArgument -> Argument
>
> Variable`<T>` -> Variable -> LocationRefrence

So how could these assignment work without a type mismatch error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*OutArgument<T>* has an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) [from *Variable* to *OutArgument<T>*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd484841.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. It seemes I need to refresh my C# knowledge.